# pyspark select column dynamically and write to single column

Tags: apache-spark

I have a pyspark dataframe generated from graphframe and number of columns is dynamic

For example

```
 From   e0      v0      e1      v1      e2       v2
 Test   exm1    ver1    exm2    ver2    exm3    ver3
```

Output expected 
Only transpose columns starts with e*
so output -

```
exm1    
exm2    
exm3
```

But number of column is dynamic , so if below is the dataframe -

```
From    e0       v0      e1     v1       e2      v2     e3       v3
Test    exm1    ver1    exm2    ver2    exm3    ver3    exm4    ver4
```

So output -

```
exm1    
exm2    
exm3    
exm4
```

made some progress on that , concat columns to an array and explode .

```
filteredPaths1.select ( explode (array ( col("from.id") , col("v1.id"), col("v2.id"), col("v3.id"), col("v4.id"), col("v5.id"), col("v6.id") ).alias("arr1"))   )
```

Can the column names select dynamically , like concat columns only starts with v , so it can dynamically select v0...v6 and provide the output ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`list comprehension`** and **`explode array`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
#|From|  e0|  v0|  e1|  v1|  e2|  v2|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
#|Test|exm1|ver1|exm2|ver2|exm3|ver3|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *


#or using in
df.select(explode(array(*[x for x in df.columns if 'e' in x]))).show()

#using startswith
df.select(explode(array(*[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('e')]))).show()
#+----+
#| col|
#+----+
#|exm1|
#|exm2|
#|exm3|
#+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Wasn't able to up-vote because of my reputation is less , once it crosses I will :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define the columns list dynamically, like:

```
columns_of_interest = [col for col in df.schema.fields if col.name.startsWith('e')]
df = df.select(explode(array(*columns_of_interest)))
```

Not sure if I got what do you want to do with columns of interest. If that's not the expected behaviour - let me know

Comment: Please let me know what if f in "f.name.startsWith('e')" .....error "   NameError: name 'f' is not defined "

Comment: This one worked - "columns_of_interest = [ item[0] for item in filteredPaths1.dtypes if item[0].startswith('v')]" .... Thanks for showing the direction

Comment: @PratikRudra fixed the issue